# Troubleshooting Leaflet JS tapping issues on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, leaflet

Leaflet JS is great, and I have a map that works beautifully when accessed on a PC (https://scmaker.site/dig21/). But when I access it on a touchscreen device, it is difficult to trigger some events correctly. For instance:, I use this command to toggle the sidebar on/off by just clicking anywhere on the map.

```
function onMapClick(e) {
sidebar.toggle();}
```

It works fine on PC, but on mobile when I tap it usually justs moves the mpa to a side a bit and doesn't open the sidebar. I'm guessing it not working well on mobile has to do with how the click event is handled on mobile devices, but I'm not sure if there is an easy way to make it work correctly on both. On mobile, I can sometimes trigger the above correctly by holding my finger down for a short while, or by swiping a short distance, but this is glitchy at best.

The (easy)buttons on the left also seem to sometimes click multiple times at once or not at all on mobile (and, again, work perfectly on PC).

FYI: I am using https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar to create the sidebar, and https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton to create the buttons. I don't really know if these plug-ins have been updated to make use of how leaflet now handles taps/gestures (which I believe got updated in the last year.)

I set up  test map where I added the following to try to disable a few things to try and get it to work right, but it still doesn't seem to work: https://scmaker.site/dig21/indextap.html

```
var digmap = L.map('mapid', {doubleClickZoom: false, touchZoom: false,  dragging: false}).setView([26.079441, -80.244651], 16);
```

Though I say that it doesn't work, sometimes when I'm on mobile, the taps seem to work perfectly for a short time, then they stop working again.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Works fine for me, all taps lead to a single click. Obviously this depends on user dexterity on touchscreen though.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback, @ghybs. My only touchscreen at the moment is a 3 years old iPad, so maybe that has something to do with the issues I'm having. I thought about checking some emulators, but I'm not sure they accurately show the difference between taps and clicks.